# Multiple plots using same axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I have a pop-up menu (used GUIDE to create it.) which calls 3 functions

1. first function gives out a scatter plot of 14x14x14
2. second function plots a bar graph of 4x1 (dynamic data)
3. third function plots an Mx14 (dynamic data)

the thing all these use the same axes `axes(handles.someName)`.

I tried putting `axes` focus on every switch statement

```
function plot_options_popup_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

str = get(hObject, 'String');
val = get(hObject, 'Value');

switch str{val};
    case 'Final Reading'
        YesNo = evalin('base','exist(''eeg_output_1d'',''var'')');
         axes(handles.eeg_final)
        if(YesNo == 1)
            plot(evalin('base','eeg_output_1d'));
        else
            return;
        end
    case 'Activation Plot'
        axes(handles.eeg_final)
        activation
    case 'Emotion State'
        axes(handles.eeg_final)
        emo_Callback
end
```

And when I change the option to a new one, the focus changes to the dynamic data which is continuously plotting.

Is there any way I could ask to GUI to stick to the thing what I want to and plot the dynamic data in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not very clear sorry. What is in the `activation` and `emo_callback` functions? Have you tried `hold on`? Can you give more details please? Thanks!

Comment: All graphing function (`plot`,`scatter` and `bar` included) can take an optional argument `Parent` which will define the axes in which they will be plotted (so if you use this argument you don't need to "focus the axes" before the plot). That aside, @Benoit_11 is right, you need to give more details, and also have a good look at the [`hold`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) function and/or at the `NextPlot` property of the [`axes properties`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)

Comment: @Benoit_11 an activation function gives a scatter plot (which is static) where as `emo_callback` is a dynamic data, which updates every second. so I used bar graph to plot it. And Hold on would hold the current graph and draw over it, which is not what I wanted to do, instead draw in separate graphs, but only show whats selected and the new figure which is being generated in by `emo_callback` function should not be visible.

Comment: @Hoki you mean to say `axes(handles.eeg_final, someVariable)` I have even tried this but this gives me an error.

Comment: No. I meant `plot( x,y, 'Parent',handles.eeg_final)` will plot `y` vs `x` in the axes pointed by the handle `handles.eeg_final`. The same principle applies for `scatter` and `bar` graphs. For your problem, you need to use `hold on` to first plot the 3 initial graphs (the plot, scatter and bar). Once these graph exist, if you have to update it you can do that by using `set(handles.yourplot, 'XData',updatedX,'YData',updatedY)` etc ... where `handles.yourplot` is the handle of the graph you want to update (you have to retrieve the handle when you first create the graph.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have data constantly updating in the background, while in the foreground you overlay some image? If so, maybe you can create two separate axes in GUIDE, one in the background for the moving data, one in the foreground for the overlay.

To make the foreground axes transparent, call `set(yourAxes, 'Color', 'none')` after drawing in it.